# HTML site doing weird optimization once published?

Tags: html, css, optimization, layout

I just published my site earlier today and I noticed a few things were different when it was actually up and running. This is what I coded looked like

[image]

And this is what it looked like when i pulled up the site on my phone

[image]

There were even a few things wrong when I pulled it up on my computer, making me question if these are even optimization problems.... I'll leave the code below if anyone can help me keep all the aspects of my site in one place no matter the viewing device that would be amazing!

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "My Custom Font";
  src: url(fonts/font.ttf) format("truetype");
}

body {
  background: url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "My Custom Font", Times, serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#headerbg {
  height: 450px;
  width: 710px;
  background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 345px;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 605px;
  right: 210px;
}

#inputbg {
  width: 375px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
  position: relative;
  left: 168px;
  bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.input {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 320px;
  left: 170px;
}

#firsttxt {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 900px;
  left: 45px;
  color: white;
}

#lasttxt {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 938px;
  left: 187px;
  color: white;
}

#emailtxt {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 933px;
  left: 103px;
  color: white;
}

#downloadhere {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1512px;
  left: 169px;
}

#enterbtn {
  width: 135px;
  height: 50px;
  color: rgb(186, 209, 225);
  background-color: rgb(203, 38, 38);
  border-color: rgb(203, 38, 38);
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#benefits {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1900px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.pdfdisplay {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 860px;
  left: 175px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>P2 Fitness Company</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div id="headerbg"></div>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>FREE PDF WITH 7 TIPS TO BOOST <br>YOUR PROGRESS IN THE GYM</h>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="img/p2fitnesstransparent.png" width="350px" height="150px">
    </div>
    <div id="inputbg"></div>

    <div class="input">
      <form method="get" action="files/7tips.pdf">
        <input type="text" name="first" size="15">
        <input type="text" name="last" size="15"> <br> <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" size="20"> <br> <br>
        <input id="enterbtn" type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="pdfdisplay">
      <img src="img/pdfdisplay.png" height="400px" width="400px">
    </div>
    <h5 id="firsttxt">FIRST*</h5>
    <h5 id="lasttxt">LAST*</h5>
    <h5 id="emailtxt">EMAIL*</h5>

    <img src="img/downloadhere.png" id="downloadhere">

  </center>

  <div id="benefits">
    <h2>BENEFITS OF PDF</h2>

    <h3>-Utilize the the time you are<br>already spending in the gym</br>
      -Learn new ways to gain muscle</br>
      -Learn to live a healthier lifestyle</br>
      -Reduce risk of injury</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you have hard-coded the dimensions using `px`. So the page is not responsive. If you want to make it work perfectly then you have to make it responsive to different viewports.
[BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a good option for making pages responsive. Also, you can make it responsive by exploiting the `vw`,`vh` and `vmin` properties.
This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) from w3schools might help you as well.